# How do I access properties of non-fired LinkButtons in an ASP RepeaterControl?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linkbutton, asprepeater

I have a navigation bar which is dynamically populated with LinkButtons by an ASP repeaterControl.

I have no problem accessing, and setting properties for the clicked LinkButton. This I can do using the sender object from the fired LinkButton. Once a LinkButton is clicked, it is highlighted in bold.

**My problem is to clear the bold property of the previously clicked linkButton when a new LinkButton ( another RepeaterItem within the same repeater) is clicked.**

Any ideas on this, please? Many thanks!

ps.
I cannot access the buttons through their ID, since they all have the same ID within the repeater.

I have unique arguments on each RepeaterItem (CommandArgument), but when I try to iterate through all linkbuttons, only static linkbuttons are found, none inside the repeater. See below:

```
Dim c As Control
For Each c In Form1.Controls
    If TypeOf c Is LinkButton Then
        MsgBox(DirectCast(c, LinkButton).CommandArgument)
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
For each item as RepeaterItem in YourRepeaterControl.Items

    Dim button as LinkButton = item.FindControl("YourLinkButtonId")
    If button IsNot Nothing Then
        'Do whatever you want here
    End If

Next
```